# Hyper-V Performance Monitor Counters

Tags: performance, hyper-v, perfmon, hypervisor

Is there any ultimate Hyper-V Performance Monitor Counters guide from Microsoft I can use to see the official (not blog-posted) information of what each counter does and how it should be used?

It is felt that google doesn't know any, some people say it doesn't even exist.

Comment: What kind of counters? Hardware performance like cycles, instructions, branches, cache accesses; or software counters - how many times hypervisor functions were called (hypercalls, trapping priviledged accesses to emulate msr, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so official but still looks legit: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrisavis/2013/03/25/performance-management-monitoring-cpu-resources/

Answer (score 0):

Found this (using DuckDuckGo ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/hyper-v-server/detecting-virtualized-environment-bottlenecks

Is this what you are looking for?